# selecting value from "bootstrap dropdown" in selenium webdriver?

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

Tool: Selenium Webdriver

I am trying to click on a specific value from a drop-down list. I can do the same via following:

HTML snippet: via "Select" attribute

```
<select class="regionpicker-state span3 ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-change="updateSelection()" ng-options="a.code as a.name for a in state" ng-model="selectedState">
  <option class="" value="">Select</option>
  <option value="0">Karnataka</option>
  <option value="1">Tamil Nadu</option>
</select>
```

Option 1 for automation: via "Select" attribute

```
 @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='organization_chosen']/a/span")
   public static WebElement organizationExpand;
 new Select(organizationExpand).selectByVisibleText("abc");
```

But, the above "option 1" code works if the code has "Select" attribute.

What if the devs have coded dropdowns by using "[bootstrap dropdown](http://www.benknowscode.com/2013/12/bootstrap-dropdown-button-select-box-control.html)" approach?

HTML snippet: via "bootstrap dropdown" approach:

```
<select id="organization" class="focused" data-placeholder="Choose a organization..." name="organization" style="display: none;">
   <div id="organization_chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-active" style="width: 220px;" title="">
      <a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="chosen-drop">
         <div class="chosen-search">
         <ul class="chosen-results">
           <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">Demo</li>
           <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">abc</li>
           <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3" style="">def</li>
           <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4" style="">xyz</li>
         </ul>
```

Comment: From what i see from the html snippet, you can directly open the underlying drop down list by clicking on the inverted triangle. then identify the li element by directly hitting the xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found for bootstrap dropdown menu:

```
@FindBy(xpath =".//*[@id='organizationType_chosen']/a/span") //this xpath is referring the path where we can click on expanding the drop-down
    public static WebElement orgTypeExpand;
@FindBy(xpath =".//*[@id='organizationType_chosen']/div/ul") //this xpath is referring to exact location to the <ul> attribute which will be visible in HTML DOM structure only after you expand the drop-down
    public static WebElement orgTypeDropDown;

public static void organizationTypeBootStrapDropDownValueSelection(String organizationTypeValue)//consider parameter passed for 'organizationTypeValue' is 'abc' value from drop-down
{
    int flag=0;
    orgTypeExpand.click();
    //Do a implicit wait here until the dropdown menu expands as the HTML Dom structure dynamically gets updated with each dropdown values once the drop-down expands. 

    List<WebElement> organizationType = orgTypeDropDown.findElements(By.className("active-result")); //retrieve all values from the drop-down. Note: This pageobject 'orgTypeDropDown' has slight different xpath than 'orgTypeExpand'
    flag=0;
    for (WebElement orgType : organizationType) //For each value retrieved check if it matches with our expected value to be clicked 'organizationTypeValue'
    {   
        if (orgType.getText().equals(organizationTypeValue)) 
        {
            orgType.click();
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(flag==1, "OrganizationType '" + organizationTypeValue + "' passed as parameter is a mismatch with values available in organization Type drop-down...");//This will assist you in making sure if the drop-down value was clicked or not. It fails if the value is not selected & stops the script execution
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can evaluate JavaScript on the page which means you can run jQuery the the page as well.

I have implemented similar solution within test complete. Sure it can be done for you. Try something like below.

```
selenium.getEval("var window = this.browserbot.getUserWindow();window.jQuery('#organizationType_chosen').selectpicker('val', '1')");
```

Refer to http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ for useful select picker api

Answer (score 0):

The following works as well (based on @Ranjit Kancharla 's idea, using PhantomJS web driver):

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver driver = ...
driver.executeScript("$('#" + id +"').selectpicker('val', '" + value + "');");
```

**id** - id of the "select" element;**value** - selected value from the "option" element